# Gas Fireplace with inconsistent ignition and maintenance of flame

Tags: gas, fireplace

New to gas fireplaces.

I have a 3yo Heat& Glo Everest vented gas fireplace with handheld starter. Have always had trouble getting it to ignite but once it ignited in the past, the flame held for as long as I wanted it on.

In the last month, have had a very difficult time just getting it to ignite(minimum 5-10 times a session and then when it finally would ignite, the flame would die out after 1-2 minutes. Would go thru 3-5 of the above cycles and then the flame would hold and be good for as many hours as I wanted it on.

Additional information:  the pilot sparks on ignition followed by a good blue/some red flame that seems to extend over and heat up the thermocouple and thermopile. I see no obvious debris on the these structures. The hood of the pilot tube appears intact. I see no wind effect on the igniting flame. There is also a thermistor.

Was thinking it was a thermocouple/pile problem but was confused as to why once I got a “good” cycle it stayed on.

Would welcome any insights.